# How to stretch Imagview in xml layout and show other button to left of it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm using Relativelayout within cardview layout to show the user details.  But I want to show the two button at the end with equal width on and everything in the left side of Image which will stretch from Top to bottom.

But I'm not able to do so.

here is my xml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    >


  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:src="@drawable/binil"
        android:padding="1dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:padding="5dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Sagar Rawal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_mobile"
        android:text="9868336847"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Jumla"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_mobile" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="searchbbc1881@gmail.com"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_mobile"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />





        <ImageButton
          android:layout_below="@+id/contact_email"
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <ImageButton
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call"
               android:layout_below="@+id/contact_email"
                 android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My output is 
[image]

But I want something similar to this
[image]

Where two buttons will equally stretch to left side of Image.

Please help

Comment: Tried using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LinearLayout weightSum like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1!" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update:
  Replace your code with this, it will solve your issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Sagar Rawal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_mobile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
                android:text="9868336847"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_mobile"
                android:text="Jumla"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contact_mobile"
                android:text="searchbbc1881@gmail.com"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contact_email"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/call"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_email"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_email"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reorganize it this way:

[image]